# Different behavior of Unicode emoji between PC and Android on Discord

Tags: unicode, discord, python-3.7, discord.py, python-unicode

I am trying to programmatically generate a small map using Python and discord.py, using Unicode characters to fill it.  It works fine on PC, however when I look at what shows on the Android Discord application I see a bunch of not-found emoji.

The strange thing is that I don't believe that these are non-standard.  Just white and black squares at present.  On Android, I can go to the emoji keyboard built into Discord and I can send these characters with no problem.

I'm not certain if this is a Unicode thing, a Python thing, or how I'm building my Discord embed.  This is what it looks like on PC:

[image: PC screenshot]

And on Android:

[image: Android screenshot]

I have a 2D array that just tacks on Unicode to a string, which then populates my embed code in `discord.py`:

```
# Render to embed
map_str = ""
for line in map_:
  for m in line:
    if m   == "#": map_str += "\U00002B1B" # non-diggable
    elif m == ".": map_str += "\U000025AB" # walkable
    elif m == ">": map_str += "\U0001F53A" # up stairs
    elif m == "<": map_str += "\U0001F53B" # down stairs
    elif m == "!": map_str += "\U0001F379" # potion
    elif m == "@": map_str += "\U0001F476" # user
    else: map_str += "\U00001425" # error
  map_str += "\n"

  embed = discord.Embed(title="Room 1", description=map_str, color=0xf43f4c)
  msg   = await cc.send(embed=embed)
```

I have tried this with normal Unicode, extended (as shown with the extra 0's), and straight up copy/pasting the emoji into the script.  Same behavior.

Comment: You might have more success using the [Box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).

Comment: They do show, however now I have run into font width issues.  The debugging continues :)

Comment: Looks like there is used a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) on PC while it's not fully true on Android. I don't  state that it's a  variable-width font on Android however apparently characters above BMP  (Unicode points greater than 0xFFFF) are rendered with double width there.